# R: build a list from separate key value columns

Tags: r, list, dictionary

In R, I'd like to build a key-value paired list from separate key and value columns. In python I would just do something like this:

```
d = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys, values)}
```

I want something similar in R that is equivalent to:

```
list('key1' = 'value1', 'key2' = 'value2', ...)
```

I've built this with a for-loop but was hoping there is a more elegant R way of doing this.

Comment: Actually, I think that might be perfect! Make an answer of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` to get a list of key/value pair

```
 split(values, keys)
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj The OP didn't provide an example data.  But can you try it on `values <- 1:5;
 keys <- 21:25`